# how to delete char after -> without using a regular expression

Tags: python

Given a string s representing characters typed into an editor,
with "->" representing a delete, return the current state of the editor.
For every one "->" it should delete one char.  If there are two "->" i.e "->->" it should delete 2 char post the symbol.

Example 1

```
Input
s = "a->bcz"
Output
"acz"
```

Explanation

The "b" got deleted by the delete.

Example 2

```
Input 
s = "->x->z"
Output
empty string
```

Explanation

All characters are deleted. Also note you can type delete when the editor
is empty as well.
"""
I Have tried following function but id didnt work

```
def delete_forward(text):
"""
return the current state of the editor after deletion of characters 
"""
f = "->"
for i in text:
    if (i==f):
        del(text[i+1])
```

How can i complete this without using regular expressions?

Comment: is the input in example 2 supposed to be `->x->z` and not `->x->-z`

Comment: thats because that function only works with *one* character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive solution-

```py
# Constant storing the length of the arrow
ARROW_LEN = len('->')

def delete_forward(s: str):
    try:
        first_occurence = s.index('->')
    except ValueError:
        # No more arrows in string
        return s
    if s[first_occurence + ARROW_LEN:first_occurence + ARROW_LEN + ARROW_LEN] == '->':
        # Don't delete part of the next arrow
        next_s = s[first_occurence + ARROW_LEN:]
    else:
        # Delete the character immediately following the arrow
        next_s = s[first_occurence + ARROW_LEN + 1:]
    return delete_forward(s[:first_occurence] + s[first_occurence + ARROW_LEN + 1:])
```

Remember, python strings are immutable so you should instead rely on string slicing to create new strings as you go.

In each recursion step, the first index of `->` is located and everything before this is extracted out. Then, check if there's another `->` immediately following the current location - if there is, don't delete the next character and call `delete_forward` with everything after the first occurrence. If what is immediately followed is not an arrow, delete the immediately next character after the current arrow, and feed it into `delete_forward`.

This will turn `x->zb` into `xb`.

The base case for the recursion is when `.index` finds no matches, in which case the result string is returned.

### Output

```py
>>> delete_forward('ab->cz')        
'abz'
>>> delete_forward('abcz')   
'abcz'
>>> delete_forward('->abc->z')
'bc'
>>> delete_forward('abc->z->')   
'abc'
>>> delete_forward('a-->b>x-->c>de->f->->g->->->->->')
'a->x->de'
```

Comment: ``input_text = "a-->b>x-->c>de->f->->g->->->->->"`` for this input it returns ``ae``  where it should return  ``output_text = "a->x->de"``

Comment: @venkat0107 should be fixed now

Comment: Why is `next_s` not being used? Looks like there is a bug: `delete_forward('a-->b>x-->c>de->f->->g->->->->->')` gives me `'ae>g>>'` and `delete_forward('a->b->->ddb->cc')` gives me `'a>ddbc'`.

Answer (score 7):

Strings do not support item deletion. You have to create a new string.

```
>>> astring = 'abc->def'
>>> astring.index('->')  # Look at the index of the target string
3
>>> x=3
>>> astring[x:x+3]  # Here is the slice you want to remove
'->d'
>>> astring[0:x] + astring[x+3:]  # Here is a copy of the string before and after, but not including the slice
'abcef'
```

This only handles one '->' per string, but you can iterate on it.

Comment: You could also do `astring.replace(astring[x:x+3], '')` instead of `astring[0:x] + astring[x+3:]` as a means of directly constructing the new string (not different enough to warrant a new answer). If there are multiple copies of `astring[x:x+3]` it'll get 'em all, but you'd have to loop until `index('->')` raised an error to be sure you got all `->X` sequences out of the string. (This is not a criticism, to be clear; I up-voted)

Comment: It's worth noting that str.index will throw a `ValueError` if the substring is not found.

Answer (score 2):

There could be several methods to achieve this in python e.g.:

### Using split and list comprehensions (If you want to delete a single character everytime one or more delete characters encountered):

```
def delete_forward(s):
    return ''.join([s.split('->')[0]] + [i[1:] if len(i)>1 else "" for i in s.split('->')[1:]])
```

Now `delete_forward("a->bcz")` returns `'acz'` & `delete_forward("->x->z")` returns `''`. ote that this works for EVERY possible case whether there are many delete characters, one or none at all. Moreover it will NEVER throw any exception or error as long as input is `str`. This however assumes you want to delete a single character everytime one or more delete characters encountered.

### If you want to delete as many characters as the number of times delete characters occur:

```
def delete_forward(s):
    new_str =''
    start = 0
    for end in [i for i in range(len(s)) if s.startswith('->', i)] +[len(s)+1]:
        new_str += s[start:end]
        count = 0
        start = max(start, end)
        while s[start:start+2] =='->':
            count+=1
            start+=2
        start += count
    return new_str
```

This produces same output for above two cases however for case: `'a->->bc'`, it produces `'a'` instead of `'ac'` as produced by first function.

Comment: this works when there is one car deletion but it should also delete 2 chars if it finds two
ex:- ``input_text = "ab->->cde->f" output_text = "abe"``

Comment: Ohh I see! It wasnt mentioned in your question so I assumed you wanna delete only one character regardless of number of times a delete character occurs. There are ways like the function Im gonna add now